# Codemirror display code from codemirror textarea

Tags: codemirror

I'm getting plain text while displaying the code from the codemirror textarea and I want to that in the form of code highlighted format. Any plz help me.

I want to print highlighted code which was highlighted in the codemirror editor I'm getting that code from codemirror editor by using `editor.getValue();`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo_Format</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
        <script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/util/formatting.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/css.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/xml.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/htmlmixed.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/docs.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            .CodeMirror {
                border: 1px solid #eee;
            }

            td {
                padding-right: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>

        <form>
            <textarea id="code" name="code">
                package org;import java.io.IOException;import javax.servlet.http.*;@SuppressWarnings("serial")
                public class BasicChatServlet extends HttpServlet{public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException{resp.setContentType("text/plain");resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");}}
            </textarea>

        </form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:autoFormatSelection()">
                        <button> Format </button>
                    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button id="copy_button">copy</button>
                    <button id="show">show</button>
                </td>
                <div id="code_show">

                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </p>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#copy_button").click(function(){
            $("textarea").select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
          });

          var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            lineNumbers: false,
            indentUnit: 4

          });
          CodeMirror.commands["selectAll"](editor);
          function getSelectedRange() {
            return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
          }
          function autoFormatSelection() {
            var range = getSelectedRange();
            var x=editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);

          }
          $("#show").click(function(){
             var program=editor.getValue();
             $("#code_show").text(program);
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure if this answers your question because it's not very clear -- it would be helpful if you only provided the necessary code for the question)

Each mode (which styles your CodeMirror instance) lives in a subdirectory of the `mode/` directory, and typically defines a single JavaScript file that implements the mode. Loading such file will make the language available to CodeMirror through the [`mode` option](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_mode), which you declare while creating your CodeMirror instance:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  lineNumbers: false,
  indentUnit: 4,
  mode: 'text/css'
});
```

You'll need to ensure your [different mode files](https://codemirror.net/mode/) are added to a mode folder in your library. In your case the `css.js`, `xml.js`, `javascript.js` and `htmlmixed.js` files need to be in a new folder called lib/mode (so `css.js` has a filepath of lib/mode/css.js for example).

You can inspect each mode's demo to see what string you must pass to the `mode:` option in order for it to be called. Here's the [css demo for example](https://codemirror.net/mode/css/index.html)

You can go one step further and change the mode on the fly for editing multiple text file-types: [Multiple modes Codemirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547506/multiple-modes-codemirror)